# Cygwin and trouble with quote marks

Tags: cygwin, quotes

I have an trouble with cygwin and qoutemarks.

This works:

```
grep FOO /path/to/files\ with\ spaces/*
grep FOO "/path/to/files with spaces/file1.txt"
```

But this does not:

```
grep FOO "/path/to/files with spaces/*"  
grep FOO '/path/to/files with spaces/*'
```

The error messange is: grep: /path/to/files with spaces/*: No such file or directory

It the asterisk interpreted in some special way or am I missing something completely obvious, or is something weird going on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you running inside bash? `man bash` for the full details.

Basically, wildcard expansion is done by the *shell* in unix, not by the commands themselves. Let's say that I have four files, `a`, `b`, `c` and `d` in my folder. `set -x` tells bash to echo the command it is actually going to attempt to run after it has munged what you typed, so we'll use that here.

```
$ set -x
$ echo *
+ echo a b c d
a b c d
```

That line starting `+` is printed by bash: bash actually passes `a b c d` to `echo`. `echo` never sees the `*` you typed.

```
$ echo "*"
+ echo '*'
*
```

This time you told bash not to do filename expansion on the `*` by quoting it. Thus `echo` now sees the `*`.

As for your original query, try

```
grep FOO '/path/to/files with spaces/'*
```